# How to invoke asynchronous Lambda function using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have created a asynchronous lambda function that is running fine when I am testing it on aws console. It is taking 6-7 mins to complete the execution. But when I am calling the same function from my local aws cli it is showing the below output.

```
Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/mandrill/invocations"
```

Any idea whats going wrong and how can I resolve that. The command I am using to invoke this function from cli is below,

```
aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name mandrill --region us-east-1 --payload "{ \"domain\": \"faisal999.wombang.com\" }" --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [invoke a function asynchronously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html), set InvocationType to Event.

```
aws lambda invoke --invocation-type Event --function-name mandrill --region us-east-1 --payload "{ \"domain\": \"faisal999.wombang.com\" }" --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json
```

Additionally, consider the following:

For asynchronous invocation , Lambda adds events to a queue before sending them to your function. If your function does not have enough capacity to keep up with the queue, events may be lost. Occasionally, your function may receive the same event multiple times, even if no error occurs. To retain events that were not processed, configure your function with a dead-letter queue .

Answer (score 1):

In your command you have `--invocation-type RequestResponse`

From the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html):

> `RequestResponse` (default) - Invoke the function **synchronously**. Keep the connection open until the function returns a response or times out. The API response includes the function response and additional data.

You may want to try it with `--invocation-type Event`.

> `Event` - Invoke the function **asynchronously**. Send events that fail multiple times to the function's dead-letter queue (if it's configured). The API response only includes a status code.